# Excel formula using a formula for date transformation with or iserror

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Background: The data is coming from a DB with dates in European format (DD/MM/YYYY). The "Created" column (Column A) also has a timestamp in the 24h format. Next to it is the "Identified" column (column B), with just a date, that may not be the same as the "created" date.

My output needs to be a new "Created" column with just the date (no timestamp) in the US format, which I know how to do. I use LEFT to capture just the European date in a new column. (column C)
Then in another new column I use =Date(value(right(A2,4)),value(mid(A2,4,2)),value(left(a2,2))) to rearrange the date into the US format (MM/DD/YYYY). (Column D)

All good with the above. Here's where it gets sticky, I need to do the same date conversation to the "Identified" data into it's own column (Column E). Not every row of data has an "Identified" date.

In cases where there is no "Identified" date, I would like my Date formula to recognize the error (which appears as #VALUE) and copy the converted "Created" date.

I've tried playing with IF, OR and IsError statements, but can't seem to get one that is valid.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I also tried to create another column (F) using =If(iserror) to read my converted "Identified" column, and if it was an error, to grab the converted "Created" date, and if not an error, to grab the converted "Identified" date, however that gives me an empty cell.

I have punched up a simple example excel sheet, but I don't see the option of where to upload/attach the excel file?

[Image of sampleworkbook with formulas commented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3cKR.jpg)

Comment: Please add some sample data with desired output, that'd make your question easier to understand

Comment: instead of `iserror` use `iferror` or possibly `ifna`

Comment: In the days before IFERROR became available (prior to Excel 2007), the way to have handled this would have been to use an IF for cells in column E with the condition part identifying not the error itself but the cause of the error (an empty cell in column B). The true and false parts of the IF would then have been used create the result you want based on the cell in column B or in column D as appropriate. IFERROR provides an alternative and simpler approach, which avoids the need to identify the cause of the error but instead simply traps the error.

Comment: Thank you. I'm struggling to get the formula to work properly. I did put a picture in my post with a mockup of the situation I'm dealing with (with one typo, where I put an indicator arrow and said "D2" but meant "D3"). Any assistance with how this formula would be written in combination with the DATE would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula for cell `E2`...

Old way, using IF

`=IF(ISBLANK(B2),D2,DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(B2,4)),VALUE(MID(B2,4,2)),VALUE(LEFT(B2,2))))`

Modern way, using IFERROR

`=IFERROR(DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(B2,4)),VALUE(MID(B2,4,2)),VALUE(LEFT(B2,2))),D2)`

If `B2` is empty then the `DATE` function you had in `E2` yields an error.

The old way uses an `IF` function to test if cell `B2` is empty and, if it is, simply delivers as its result whatever is in cell `D2`. If the test fails, the `IF` function simply calculates the required result using the `DATE` function.

The modern way is not concerned with what causes the `DATE` to be in error, just whether or not there is an error. If there is no error, the IFERROR function uses the first argument - the `DATE` function - and if there is an error it uses the second argument - `D2` - as its result.

The modern way is preferable. Other errors, such as `B2` containing random text, will cause problems with the `DATE` function in E2. The `IF` version won't deal with such errors properly whereas `IFERROR` will.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was over-complicating it, for some reason I thought I still needed an "OR" function in there, so you can imagine the errors I was getting ('too few arguments...' among others). Your IFERROR formula worked beautifully.